# Sheets: How to make function copy range to last row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

[image]

I have a script set to copy the values of A3:B12.
I'm trying to make it so I can use VLOOKUP to find these values, but it combines them all onto one row (A13:T13 here).
This is the script I'm using:

```
function STlogWeeksLabor() {
  var todaysSales = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('Streeterville Labor Log!STLaborImport');
  var logSheet = todaysSales.getSheet();
  logSheet.appendRow(
    todaysSales.getValues()
    .reduce(function(a, b) { return a.concat(b); }) // flatten the 2D array to 1D
  );
}
```

A3:B12 = 'Streeterville Labor Log!STLaborImport'

Trying to find a way to copy/paste this with the same format and amount of rows/columns (A3:B12).

Comment: What is the name of the logSheet?

Comment: Same sheet, 

```
Streeterville Labor Log
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function STlogWeeksLabor() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var rg=sh.getRange('A3:B12');
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow()+1,1,vA.length,vA[0].length).setValues(vA);
}
```

Comment: I'm getting the same result with this, copying all values to one row.

Comment: Isn't that what you want?  You were using appendRow.

Comment: Please describe what you want the output to look like.  Don't assume that I know what a vLookup is because I don't.

Comment: I suppose that’s where I went wrong then, I’d like the values to be copied and pasted in their current format. So A3:B12 would copy/paste to next open row, in this case A13:B22.

Comment: Okay try it again.